# problems on permutation and combination

Tags: combinations

Find the total number of combinations by taking at least one green and one blue ball from five different green, four different blue and three different red balls?

Comment: What do you mean by "at least"

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  When you pose a question here, it is expected that you include any work you have done on the problem and indicate where you are stuck so that you receive responses that address the specific difficulties you are encountering.

Answer (score 1):

Since you use the word "combination" I assume you are implying that the order doesn't matter, but that each of the different colored balls are distinct. In choosing 3 balls the number of ways to get what you describe is 5*4. But since order doesn't matter, you divide by 2 factorial, which is 6. So this is:
$$\frac{(5)(4)}{2!} = \frac{20}{2} =10$$.